# Netsuite Item fulfilment is giving "Notice: service is not allowed"

Tags: netsuite, fedex

I have setup Fedex shipping and integrated shipping labels in Netsuite and I am trying to test print labels. I am running into an issue where I get an error when I try to "Save and Print Label" on Item Fulfillment when I am using the new Fedex shipping method that says "Notice Service not allowed."
If I uncheck the box for "Integrated Shipping Label" I can save the item fulfillment without error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it not work in all roles? Check if you have the web services permission enabled in roles where it doesn't work. Also, did you get FedEx setup through NetSuite? FedEx integration is often tricky, and it's best to work with NetSuite directly. Been through it before. Let me know how it goes, I'll keep an eye out for ya.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We set it up in NetSuite ourselves using the help docs that are available. We worked with our contact at FedEx to make sure they were seeing the orders/shipments coming through on our account so that seems to be working, its just the order fulfilment that is causing issues occasionally with this "Service not allowed" notification. Not very descriptive.